# How to prevent `plot_model()` from __sjPlot__ package in __R__ extrapolate values

Tags: r, sjplot

I have just realised that `plot_model()` from **sjPlot** in **R** extrapolates values if you try to visualise lines (or curves) of a covariate for different levels of some factor. In this particular case, one level has a maximum that is far below the maximum of other two levels, but still `plot_model()` draws the line throughout. However, I would like to show the difference in the range of values between levels. The line of code looks like this:

```
p1 <- plot_model(MODEL, type='pred',
    terms=c('COVARIATE[all]', 'FACTOR'))
p1
```